# PANDAS: Execute to_excel successfully,but no output file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I use to_excel to generate excel file, no error occurred , but no output file available. can't find anything,any file in my supposed location...
And I don't know why..

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd
import openpyxl
pd.set_option('display.width',None)
DIR = 'E:\Process'
datapath =os.path.join(DIR, 'Data.xlsx')
formatpath = os.path.join(DIR, 'Format.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(datapath)
df1=pd.read_excel(formatpath)
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    target = (df.iloc[i,17])
    df2 = df1
    df2.iat[3,3] = target
    print(df2)
    filename = df.iloc[i,2]
    filename = str(filename) + ".xlsx"
    sourcepath = os.path.join(DIR, filename)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(sourcepath)
    df2.to_excel(writer)
    print(sourcepath)
```

Comment: you're writing out `df1` every single time you loop, which ends up just being what you load in from `Format.xlsx`, do you mean to write out `df2` perhaps?

Comment: yes.. It's a mistake , it should be df2..and I have changed it.

Comment: I'd probably not write to file in each iteration. Just iterate to create the dataframe and once set, write the whole dataframe to file 1 time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this question is so strange...and the data is not big, total amount of the row is around 30 maybe.. I just want to use it to do some boring office jobs.. I’ll try it tomorrow!

Comment: try adding `writer.save()` at the end of the script. Also see the link here for `pd.ExcelWriter` example usage: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: Thank you! Problem resolved after I added writer.save() at the end of each iteration.

Comment: @Codefmeister great, I've put the solution in an answer rather than just a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on the comment:

Use `writer.save()` after calling `to_excel`.

Alternatively you can use the `with` statement as suggested in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: I wonder why it worked once for me without running the "save()" command.

Comment: Instead of `writer.save()` it is also possible, and probably superior, to write `writer.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm trying to re-run this code on my local machine, I'm running into an error with setting DIR  to `'E:\Process'` because of the escaping of "\" for windows machines. Have you tried `"E:\\Process"`? or try it as a raw string literal `r'E:\Process'`?